# Use method to create multiple AlertDialog with varying behavior

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have an activity with several buttons. I want each button to open an `AlertDialog` to confirm the user's action before continuing. I am looking for a way to create a method that will set up the `AlertDialog`, pass in a string for the title and message, and then pass a result back to the activity so I can have it select what action to do. I have looked around and not been able to find a way to pass a result back to the activity, but the if statement to check the result runs before the user clicks the dialog's button.

Here is what I have so far in **Activity.java**:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String title, message;

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.settings_btn_cleardatabase:
                title = getResources().getString(R.string.settings_dialog_clearstats_title);
                message = getResources().getString(R.string.settings_dialog_clearstats_text);

                showDialog(title, message);

                // This is the part that gets bypassed before user clicks dialog button
                if (mResultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Player Scores Cleared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.settings_btn_cleargaminggroup:
                title = getResources().getString(R.string.settings_dialog_cleargroup_title);
                message = getResources().getString(R.string.settings_dialog_cleargroup_text);

                showDialog(title, message);

                if (mResultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Gaming Group Cleared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
           }
}
```

Generic Alert **Method**:

```
private void showDialog(String title, String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder clearStatsDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // Sets title
    clearStatsDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);

    // Sets message
    clearStatsDialogBuilder
            .setMessage(message)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_warning_white_24dp)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.settings_dialog_clear_confirmbtn, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mResultCode = RESULT_OK;
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.settings_dialog_clear_cancelbtn, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mResultCode = RESULT_CANCELED;
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // Create alert dialog
    AlertDialog clearStatsDialog = clearStatsDialogBuilder.create();

    // Show it
    clearStatsDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this ?

1. create your `DialogFragment` and define an interface that the `Activity` will `implement`
2. Then in the `DialogFragment` when you want to return the result to the `Activity` you cast the activity to the `interface`
3. In the Activity you implement that interface and get the values

example :

////////////  1 stage

```
        public interface DialogFragmentListener {
            public void onReturnValue(String reurnValue);
        }
```

/////////////////////////// 2 stage

```
        @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                DialogFragmentListener activityDL = (DialogFragmentListener) getActivity();
                activityDL.onReturnValue("Pass the value");
            }
```

/////////////////////////////// 3 stage

```
        public class MyActivity implements DialogFragmentListener {
            ...
            @Override
            public void onReturnValue(String returnVal) {
                Log.d("onReturnValue", "Got value " + returnVal+ " back from Dialog!");
            }
        }
```

refer ->[Using DialogFragments](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html)

Comment: That did it. I was trying not to have to make a whole `DialogFragment`, though in hindsight it would have been easier than trying to get my way to work. Thanks for your help!